# How to use a WSDL for using webservice in c# project

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

most of the time i add web reference of web service and give the path of asmx file but now i am using a UPS web service and may be this web service was developed by another technology. there is no any asmx file concept. they provide wsdl file and i just add the web reference and paste the file path of wsdl file there. i compile my project and got no error. my apps is running fine but when i create a setup project of that apps and install on another machine then i am getting object reference error. so i just do not understand why it is not running on another machine when i install it from setup but it is running fine when i run it from my machine IDE. so please guide me what i am missing. what i need to do when i will be working with wsdl and that will run fine on remote machine where wsdl file not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if there is an App.config in your Setup project included where the link to your WSDL is set and check if you have that if the link to your WSDL exists on the PC where you are installing.

And if that does not work you can always try to convert the WSDL to a DLL with the help of [this site](http://my.execpc.com/~gopalan/dotnet/webservices/webservice_csharp_client.html).